# Is it feasible to quit a PhD program, do an MS (or two) for better qualification, then begin again?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I am in my first year of a finance PhD at a top 25 program. I could get through the program and get an okay job, but my goal isn't just to be another professor, I want to be absolutely outstanding, which I think I am capable of, but I feel like right now I don't have the math and stats background to be the best, and I can't take enough electives during my coursework years to get that foundation I'm looking for. Really, I feel like my quantitative background is very lacking in comparison to the best students I know - my undergrad was unrelated to finance, math, or stats. I have a double MS in finance and economics, but not having the quant background during undergrad really puts me behind where I feel like I need to be.

Honestly I'd also like to get my PhD at a better school. Part of it is looking for better placement opportunities, part of it is looking for a better education/mentor, and part of it simply vanity I guess - if I'm going to get a PhD I want it to be the way is prefer, and I'd prefer a degree from a school I can really feel proud of.

So... what I'd LIKE to do is get an MS in statistics, an MS in math, then reapply to top 10 finance PhD programs (not only am I looking for more background, yes, I actually WANT to do this). And no, I'm not interested in just "learning after I'm an assistant professor". I don't see myself having time to get top publications while learning a bunch of background information, and I want to hit the ground running with my first job.

I've had some people tell me getting an MS in math before beginning my PhD was pointless and a waste of time, but I've discovered that a lot of the PhD advice I've been given was bad advice and I should have simply done what I thought was a good idea.

My question is whether this is a feasible plan or not, and whether quitting my current PhD to pursue one or both MS degrees would hurt my chances of being admitted to another PhD program.

Comment: You're also making several assumptions: (1) You're going to transition directly from a PhD to a professorship. (2) Courses are the only way to acquire new knowledge as a graduate student. (3) You're going to be doing the same things as a professor that you're doing as a graduate student.

Comment: 1) Yes
2) No, but extra knowledge takes extra time, which I don't really have while taking a full courseload
3) I'm unclear what you mean

Comment: How many "absolutely outstanding" professors do you know, in your field, that obtained two Master degrees before pursuing a PhD? If the answer is "none" or "few", why do you think you must have two Master's to be "absolutely outstanding"? Or, more sharply, what makes you think you will be "absolutely outstanding" if you require two Master's degrees to learn everything that you need to succeed?

Comment: Yes it is feasible, but you might want to ask other questions.

Comment: @FBolst I know of many good researchers in finance who have an MS in either math or statistics - in fact I know a number of researchers (including two at my current school) who earned a PhD in math before pursuing a PhD in finance. Most top researchers who don't have graduate degrees in math or stats had significantly better quant backgrounds than I do, or else they didn't stand out until they had been in the field for 15 years.

Comment: @user2768 I'll edit my bottom-line question

Comment: @HairyPotatoCat Do you have an MS already? What does "whether it would be damaging to reapplying" mean?

Comment: It may be different in Math/Finance, but, at least in my field, it is absurdly rare to find anyone with two PhDs. While I am not in your field, and I will leave the conversation after this comment, I think you will have to come up with an *insanely good* explanation, backed up by amazing letters of recommendation, to why you quit your PhD program to join *two* Master's program before applying to a PhD program again. Getting a stronger background to apply to a better school with the purpose of being a "outstanding" seems to be a very naive explanation, at least from my perspective.

Comment: @FBolst Thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Comment: @user2768 I've edited the question and information again.

Comment: By "quitting [your] current PhD to pursue one or [two] MS degrees" you're showing that you did not complete your PhD. That might cause concerns for anyone hiring you for another PhD. Those concerns might be eased if you can justify the relevance of the MS degrees you hope to have.

Comment: The OP previously asked about the impact on their career. (That aspect seems to have been edited out of the question.) As @FBolst mentions, there might not be any need to have two MS degrees, hence, there might not be a need for three either.